# Probability distribution in wireless channel?

Tags: reference-request, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let suppose that I have a random variable $X_{mn}=\sqrt{\left(1/d_{mn}\right)^\alpha}\times h_{mn}$ wherr $d_{mn}$ is a random variable with uniform distribution and $h_{mn}$ is a random variable with exponential distribution.

How can I get the distribution of $X_{mn}\;\forall\;m,\;n\in\mathbb {N}$ ?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I did not try a lot. I supposed the independence of $h_{mn}$ and $d_{mn}$ and I get stuck with the distribution of $\sqrt{\left(1/x\right)^{\alpha}}$ where  $x$ is uniformally distributed.

Comment: @npisinp What is the domain of support for your Uniform distribution?  Is it a standard Uniform on (0,1), or more general?

Comment: @wolfies In fact I have $M$ pairs of sources and destinations all of them a randomly distibuted following an unfiorm distribution $(0, 1)$ in a certain zone (let say a circle of radius R). The $d_{mn}$ is the distance between each pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=D^{-c}H$ with obvious notations and $x\gt0$, then $[X\gt x]=[H\gt xD^c]$ hence, by independence of $H$ and $D$, $$P(X\gt x)=E(\exp(-\lambda xD^c)).$$ Since the distribution of $D$ is known, at least in principle this expectation can be computed.

If $D$ is uniform on $(0,1)$, the change of variable $v=tu^c$ yields
$$
E(\exp(-tD^c))=\int_0^1\exp(-tu^c)\mathrm du=c^{-1}t^{-1/c}\int_0^t\mathrm e^{-v}v^{1/c-1}\mathrm dv,
$$
and the last integral is the value at $t$ of an incomplete gamma function, that is,
$$
E(\exp(-tD^c))=c^{-1}t^{-1/c}\gamma(1/c,t).
$$
Plugging in $t=\lambda x$ in this yields the complementary PDF of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You need to apply the method of [bivariate transformation](http://turing.une.edu.au/~stat354/notes/node25.html) of random variables. You can define $$X \sim U(a,b)$$ and $$Y\sim \exp(\lambda)$$ (to simplify notation, $X$ stands for your $d_{mn}$ and $Y$ for $h_{mn}$) and then define $$U=X,\qquad V=\sqrt{(1/X)^a}\cdot Y$$
Solving for $X$ and $Y$ you find that $$X=U, \qquad Y=\frac{V}{\sqrt{(1/U)^a}}$$ from which you can derive the joint pdf $f_{U,V}$ of $U,V$ (according to the above method) and then integrate with respect to $U$ to get the required pdf as the marginal pdf of $V$. (Note: Since your transformed variable $V$ is not very simple, there can arise difficulties in the calculations of the required Jacobi matrix).

Comment: These are a détour, quite unnecessary.

Comment: I mean what I wrote, which is that this approach is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Why did you delete your comment?